# 403 on google api searchanalytics.query

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to query search analytics data of my site. I'm sure that it is site I've created. But when I try to request using google-api-python-client I get 403 error:

```
x = gapi.webmasters_service.searchanalytics().query(body={"startDate": "2014-01-01", "endDate": "2014-01-01"}, siteUrl="http://seozeo.com.tr").execute()
```

Output is:

> HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/http%3A%2F%2Fseozeo.com.tr/searchAnalytics/query?alt=json
>   returned "User does not have sufficient permission for site
>   'http://seozeo.com.tr/'. See also:
>   https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2451999.">

Here is gapi class:

```
class GoogleApi(object):

    _instance = None

    def __init__(self):

        self.credentials = self._getCredentials()

        http = self.credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())

        self.webmasters_service = build('webmasters', 'v3', http=http)
        self.analytics_service = build('analytics', 'v3', http=http)


    def _getCredentials(self):

        storage = Storage("credentials_storage")

        credentials = storage.get()

        if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
            flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(
                'client_secrets.json',
                scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly',
                redirect_uri='urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob')

            auth_uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
            webbrowser.open(auth_uri)

            auth_code = raw_input('Enter the auth code: ')

            credentials = flow.step2_exchange(auth_code)

            storage.put(credentials)

        return credentials
```